# pgfplots: use `colormap` color for `jump mark` line

Tags: pgfplots, gradient

I have a `ybar interval` pgfplot with variable width intervals.
On top of each interval I am drawing a line with the interval's width (using a second plot with `jump mark left`). However, I cannot find a way to tell pgf to draw those lines in the color of the current `colormap`. Instead, they are always drawn using the color specified using `draw=`.

In my rendering below, I want the red lines to be in a color representing their y-value instead:
[image: bad rendering]

One thing that also catches my attention is that the labels alongside the `colorbar` have nothing to do with the `y` values in my actual plot, but they should.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
height,width
1,884
2,5768
3,835
4,2661
5,492
6,1349
7,486
8,1117
9,498
10,854
10,0
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    ymode=log,
    colorbar,
]
\addplot[
    ybar interval,
    fill=cyan,
    draw=none,
] table [
    col sep=comma,
    create on use/xaccum/.style={
        create col/expr=\pgfmathaccuma+\prevrow{width}
    },
    x=xaccum, y=height,
] {data.csv};
\addplot[
    jump mark left,
    draw=red, %this should be a color based on the y value
] table [
    col sep=comma,
    create on use/xaccum/.style={
        create col/expr=\pgfmathaccuma+\prevrow{width}
    },
    x=xaccum, y=height,
] {data.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you can look this question: [colorbar-question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59513/pgfplots-synchronize-the-filling-of-the-bars-with-the-colorbar)

Comment: I had seen that question before, but I don't see how it applies here. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: I see. that answer is too complicated for me, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line style is changed in changing the data format.

The `colobar` + `mesh` cannot support jump plot, so we chage the data to manually make an jump data.

The Final results are shown below:
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
height,width
1,884  
1,0  % new data
2,5768
2,0  % new data
3,835
3,0  % new data
4,2661
4,0  % new data
5,492
5,0  % new data
6,1349
6,0  % new data
7,486
7,0  % new data
8,1117
8,0  % new data
9,498
9,0  % new data
10,854
10,0  % new data
10,0
10,0  % new data
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

% Define new pgfmath function for the logarithm
% to base 10 that also works with fpu library
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    ymode=log,
    colorbar, 
    colorbar style={
      ytick={0,1}, %  only show 10^0 and 10^1 tick in colorbar
      % yticklabel retreive the 10^# function in data
      yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{10^\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult,
    },
]
\addplot[
    mesh, thick, % use mesh function
    point meta=explicit, % use the "meta expr" defined below
] table [
    col sep=comma,
    create on use/xaccum/.style={
        create col/expr=\pgfmathaccuma+\prevrow{width}
    },
    meta expr=lg10(\thisrow{height}), % transform "order" into "linear" for colorbar
    x=xaccum, y=height,
] {data.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Steps are as follow:

1. **Change the input data**: Manually fix the x axis to make constant line.

   ```
   3,835
   3,0  % new data
   ```

   The width is set 0 to make cumulative axis remain same number.
2. **Plot the mesh line with colobar**: use the `colorbar`+ `mesh` to plot the color line.
3. **Define number to order function**: this function are based on The question: [colorbar with log](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23750/log-color-bar-meta-data-in-pgfplot).

   ```
   \pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{%
     \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}%
   }
   ```

   colorbar support the data only in linear format, not in log type.
   Leaves the linear order as input data for colorbar.
4. **Write linear data to colorbar**: use the `point meta=explicit,`+`meta expr=lg10(\thisrow{height})` to feed colorbar with the linear data.
5. **Retrieve ytick format**: transform back to exponential format in the yticklabel.

   ```
   colorbar style={
     yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{10^\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult,
   },
   ```
6. **leaves the 10^0 and 10^1**: because your data range is small, I supress the ugly intermediate y ticks.

   ```
   ytick={0,1}, %  only show 10^0 and 10^1 tick in colorbar
   ```

Comment: Close enough. I can live just fine with the vertical lines :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Though I cannot completely draw what you want, I put it in the answer zone.

My output is as follow:
[image]

- As you mentioned, `draw` cannot accept `colormap`.

If you want to color the line, `mesh` is your choice.
But the `jump mark left,` conflict with `mesh` (change the order, you will get different result).

---

- **Fill color under the line**.

To do so, two plottings are combined using the `const plot` with the option `\closedcycle`.

The [colorbar-question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59513/pgfplots-synchronize-the-filling-of-the-bars-with-the-colorbar) provides the answer to fill colors, `shading`.
It should be defined before the plotting

```
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{stefan}{50bp}{
  color(0bp)=(violet);
  color(10bp)=(blue);
  color(20bp)=(green);
  color(30bp)=(yellow);
  color(40bp)=(orange);
  color(50bp)=(red)
}
```

It define the color spacing 0 to 50, every 10 change one color.

Then change the colors in colorbar:

```
    colormap={new}{
      color(0)=(violet);color(0.2)=(blue);
      color(0.4)=(green);color(0.6)=(yellow);
      color(0.8)=(orange);color(1)=(red)},
```

it divide [0,1] into 5 pieces.

---

- **Change the ytick in colorbar**

  ```
      point meta min=1,point meta max=10,
  ```

  Noting that the colorbar is for linear interpolating, not for log-type interpolation.
  That maybe the reason why `point meta=y` doesn't work fine in your case.
  I set the minimum and maximum instead.

---

whole input are list below:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}

    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    height,width
    1,884
    2,5768
    3,835
    4,2661
    5,492
    6,1349
    7,486
    8,1117
    9,498
    10,854
    10,0
    \end{filecontents}
    \usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{stefan}{50bp}{ % define shading color
      color(0bp)=(violet);
      color(10bp)=(blue);
      color(20bp)=(green);
      color(30bp)=(yellow);
      color(40bp)=(orange);
      color(50bp)=(red)
    }

    \begin{axis}[
        ymode=log,
        colorbar,
        colormap={new}{  % define colorbar color
          color(0)=(violet);color(0.2)=(blue);
          color(0.4)=(green);color(0.6)=(yellow);
          color(0.8)=(orange);color(1)=(red)},
        ymin=1,ymax=10,  
    ]
    \addplot[
        const plot,    % combine line and filling
        shading=stefan,% use the shading color
        point meta min=1,point meta max=10,% set colorbar y min and max
        draw=black,line width={0.1pt},     % set lines color and thickness
    ] table [
        col sep=comma,
        create on use/xaccum/.style={
            create col/expr=\pgfmathaccuma+\prevrow{width}
        },
        x=xaccum, y=height,
    ] {data.csv}  \closedcycle; % close the area to fill colors
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: It is indeed in the answer zone: The top of each interval has the desired color. However, my style guide won't allow me to use this :(

Comment: It seems that the pgfplots does not support the const plotting with colormap. Maybe the data can be transform into another format, for example (1,884) --(2,884) -- (2,5768) can make an **right angle**, intead of using the constant plot.